# Can you use the Resonant Utterance (Onomancy) Feat with cantrips?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, cantrips

The info I found on D&D Beyond says this:

> ***Using a Resonant:*** *You can use one Resonant when you cast a wizard spell with a spell slot and speak the true name of one creature targeted by the spell. Speaking the name is part of casting the spell.*

My question is, would cantrips count as spells in this context? My DM isn't so sure, being of the opinion that the spell needs to expend a spell slot to be applicable, but I can't find any info to support this claim.

Comment: I apologize for such a silly question. I completely misread the text. It's there, plain as day in the description. If anyone knows how to delete a question please help me hide my shame.

Comment: You should be able to delete it by pressing the deleted button on the bottom left of the post. Alternately you could edit in to specify the system (I assume adding the [dnd-5e] would suffice) and post a self-answer as you have solved your own problem. Up to you.

Comment: I posted the answer for you in case someone else comes up with the same question.

Comment: I agree with Korvin that the question still has value in case someone else has the same confusion.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is, would cantrips count as spells in this context?

### No, since cantrips do not have/use spell slots.

From Chapter 10, PHB, [Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting)

> A cantrip is a spell that can be cast at will, *without using a spell* slot and without being prepared in advance. Repeated practice has fixed the spell in the caster's mind and infused the caster with the magic needed to produce the effect over and over. A cantrip's spell level is 0.